# YTD Dax function giving incorrect result when used under direct query

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am using dax ytd fuction to show me the current ytd sale for the years 2015,2016,2017,2018 of months jan feb march, I have over 96million rows over which I am using measures. My data is over Analysis Services, and I am building my reports in powerbi using the Analysis Services there, I am doing direct query for this.

Now the main thing here is I have written a dax which takes about 30seconds to load the report that dax is:

```
YTD Sold =
VAR CurrentDate = WEEKNUM ( CALCULATE ( DATEVALUE ( MAX ( 'Bookscan'[Week Date] ) ) , ALL ( 'Bookscan'[Year of Sale] ) ) )
VAR BeginDate = 1
RETURN
CALCULATE (
[Qty Sold] ,
WEEKNUM ( DATEVALUE ( 'Bookscan'[Week Date] ) ) <= CurrentDate &&
WEEKNUM ( DATEVALUE ( 'Bookscan'[Week Date] ) ) >= BeginDate )
```

Above Dax Works correctly and gives me correct result.

However the below dax is breaking up and doesnt show me correct results as required:

```
YTD Qty Sold = TOTALYTD(SUM(Bookscan[QtySold]),Bookscan[Week Date])
```

Now the above dax is not giving me the results as required, I believe both the dax suppose to do same thing, then why the second one is breaking.

Can anyone correct me if I am not using the dax properly above??

Currently I am using the below dax which is giving me correct data for the current year:

```
YTD QTY Sale1 = CALCULATE(sum((Bookscan[QtySold])),YEAR(Bookscan[Week Date])=YEAR(TODAY()))
```

But how can I use this so that I can see the data of all the years that I have selected inside my slicer, the Year of Sale column contains the data with years.

Comment: Do you have a Date dimension in your model?

Comment: Are you using SSAS in DirectQuery mode? Then TOTALYTD is not supported at this moment, according to Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/query-bi/dax/totalytd-function-dax

Comment: yes I am using SSAS, if not supported then How can I better right the dax without TOTALYTD so that it can solve my purpose?